# Google account's password exposed after authorizing web apps to the account

Tags: passwords, google

Yesterday I registered accounts on some online storage websites. On that same day's afternoon, Google notified me about someone had has logged in using my Google account in US (clearly that's not where I live). So I had to change password and perform a whole PC scan.

[image]

What I did yesterday were:

- Register account at copy,com
- Register account at ozibox,com
- Register account at sensortower,com
- Register account at appannie,com
- Authorize website to access account at ballloon,com
- Authorize website to access account at filestream,me

Also I logged into this site but I registered long time ago:

- ge,tt

Only google account is exposed so far (at least as I know). The computer is clean. I highly doubt that the sensortower and appannie were the cause. I used the same password for all account unless the site didn't allow it (stupid yes but this account is not my main account).

**This is strange because if the hacker just tried the password from website to access to my Google account and accidentally succeeded then he had access to the account database of the site or he was the owner of the site himself.**

**If the hacker access my account using the Basic account info permission *(View your email address - View your basic profile info)*. Then how was that possible? He only had my email address?!**

No suspicious activity so far since I changed the password (I used the phone to change the password).

Can anyone try to replicate the attack with these sites? That would help many people from losing their accounts.

Comment: What makes you think your password was acquaired yesterday? It could have been acquaired long ago and kept in a DB sold, passed on, shared or whatever and finally been used yesterday. Since you seem to have the same password in different accounts any of those or any other place where you have used the same password could be the point where it has been acquaired.

Comment: If they got the pass long time ago then they have to test if it works or not. Or they could change the pass so I can't access and change the pass anymore (this is the most important thing). It's just too convenient that I logged into a bunch of sites and that the same day some one sneak into my account.

Comment: Did you input your google password on any of these sites? Could one of those sites have been legitimately (if wrongly and incompetently) accessing your google account on your inadvertent request? Did you install any client apps? Your assumptions here may be relying on lacking information, or may be wrong altogether...

Comment: Of course I had to input password for sites that required. But only password for the site's account not on a Google login form. All the authorizations were performed with clicking buttons. As you can see the access was on a Windows PC with Firefox browser so some one in some way has my account's info and logged in. And I hate instilling client apps so no app was installed.

Comment: @jcp0908 well, they could have tested your password yesterday. The fact that you logged in to a bunch of sites doesn't give any adventage (you have been warned by google, haven't you?), the adventage would have been you not noticing your account has been compromised. But anyone knows google keeps track and inform of possible unauthorized accesses.

Comment: As I said once you have some one's account then you have to change its password or change the access to you only else the owner may change it before you can. I haven't installed anything on my PC since Monday and I only open news sites like engadget or reddit. No logging in for quite some times. And if it has something to do with my PC then my main account should have been attacked also.

Comment: @jcp0908 changing the user password looks silly to me. Accessing a user account and being able to retrieve other sites passwords or bank accounts asking those sites to recover the "forgotten" password sending new passwords (or links to reset password) to the user's email looks more interesting to me, and to do that the user of the account should not notice the account has been compromised.

Comment: Make sense but I still have doubt on those sites listed above. If no one want to try to find the malicious cause then I'll do it myself. But only when I finish fixing my old PC.

Comment: You said "I used the same password for all account unless the site didn't allow it...". But you don't say if the password you used for all (most) of these new registrations on these sites was the same as the password you used for the Gmail account where you received the Google security notification about the attempted login. I suppose that is the case, but it's not clear.

Comment: Were you able to discover any information about which site likely did this?

Comment: I had a new suspect: zalmos [dot] com. It's a proxy site. I overlooked it last time. But after watching a video using that site, I received a notification that some one was trying to change my Facebook's password and remove my recovery phone number. I didn't use the site anymore but I have been to busy to test all the site. I'll try on a public computer.

Comment: Just had the exact same thing happen to me - I registered on AppAnnie.com with my Google account, and seconds later got an email about a suspicious login attempt from USA. AppAnnie does state [in a support page](https://support.appannie.com/hc/en-us/articles/204209254-Google-detects-a-Suspicious-login-to-my-account-why-is-that-) that this can happen, however the IP address used in my case is not the one listed there. Mine is 69.167.138.159 and when I do a whois lookup it does actually say APPANNIEEURO in the Network name, so I guess it's legit.

Comment: Yeah even though in my case the registration on AppAnnie and the alert message were 15 minutes apart, but I think it can still be the case.